# Making a generic property

Tags: c#, .net, generics, properties

I have a class that stores a serialized value and a type. I want to have a property/method returning the value already casted:

```
public String Value { get; set; }

public Type TheType { get; set; }

public typeof(TheType) CastedValue { get { return Convert.ChangeType(Value, typeof(_Type)); }
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: Generic properties would be nice; I think `var val = obj.Prop<Type>` is more succinct for a type-based lookup than `obj.Prop[typeof(Type)]` or `obj.GetProp<Type>()`.

Answer (score 112):

It's possible if the class containing the property is generic, and you declare the property using the generic parameter:

```
class Foo<TValue> {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public TValue TypedValue {
        get {
            return (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(Value, typeof(TValue));
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to use a generic method instead:

```
class Foo {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Type TheType { get; set; }

    public T CastValue<T>() {
         return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

You can also use the `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` classes to convert, since they allow a class to define it's own converter.

**Edit**: note that when calling the generic method, you must specify the generic type parameter, since the compiler has no way to infer it:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Value = "100";
foo.Type = typeof(int);

int c = foo.CastValue<int>();
```

You have to know the type at compile time.  If you don't know the type at compile time then you must be storing it in an `object`, in which case you can add the following property to the `Foo` class:

```
public object ConvertedValue {
    get {
        return Convert.ChangeType(Value, Type);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second example of class 'Foo, I am baffled : a public property 'theType is declared : "public Type TheType { get; set; }" but appears not to be used in the code. thanks,

Comment: The property was in the original example. I just left it in.

Comment: When I try Brannons solution I get a runtime error saying the object I am casting must implement IConvertible. Have I done something wrong because this seems like a deal breaker unless casting a class where I have the source available.

Answer (score 62):

Properties, events, constructors etc can't be generic - only methods and types can be generic. Most of the time that's not a problem, but I agree that sometimes it's a pain. Brannon's answer gives two reasonable workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe the example you've given here is possible. The type of CastedValue has to be defined at compile time, which means it can't depend on a runtime value (the value of the TheType property).

EDIT: Brannon's solution has some good ideas for how to handle this using a generic function rather than a property.