# How to have the return of List<T> in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to have return of `<T>` using below code, but seems I'm doing something wrong.

```
public class Chapter
{
   public Byte ChapterID { get; set; }
   public string SuraName { get; set; }
}

public class Recent
{
   public Byte RecentID{get;set;}
   public string Description{get;set;}
}

public class ChapterMenusHeader : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
List<T> _myList;
public List<T> MyList
{
   get { return _myList;}
   set {_myList = value;}
}
}
```

where `<T>` can be any generic type

I'm getting below compilation error

```
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can i have below?

```
List<Chapter> chapters = new ChapterMenusHeader().MyList;
List<Recent> myRecent = new ChapterMenusHeader().MyList;
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are trying to return result of type `Type` where as you signature is `List<T> Chapters`

Comment: shouldn't you just return _myList?

Comment: Yeah, You guys are right!

Comment: please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271347/making-a-generic-property. That's what you want.

Comment: You cannot have a property at the top level.  It has to be inside of a class.  In this case, it appears that that class should be generic.

Comment: sorry Paisios, I could not understand it. I made my post simpler understand it. I think my question is clear now.

Comment: yeah, That is inside another class. I just pasted that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

[C# Property with Generic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043939/c-sharp-property-with-generic-type)
and 
[Why aren’t there generic properties in C#?](http://newcome.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/why-arent-there-generic-properties-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class ChapterMenusHeader<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
List<T> _myList;
public List<T> MyList
{
   get { return _myList;}
   set {_myList = value;}
}
}
```

and then this:

```
List<Chapter> chapters = new ChapterMenusHeader<Chapter>().MyList;
```