# c# How could I make a property for a variable of an aggregated object?

Tags: c#, class, properties, aggregate, aggregation

I have a generic class called ref<> which I use for passing value types by reference. For example:

```
Ref<int> myInt = new Ref<int>(); //An integer that's passed by reference.
myInt.Value = 1; //Access the int by value.
```

Lets say I want myInt.Value to be a property for the class aggregating it (but not for the Ref<> class). Like:

```
myInt.Value
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

Let's say I have a class called Car which has a Ref called Mileage. In main, I want to be able to get/set myCar.Mileage.Value as if it were a property and had getter/setter logic, but I want to write that logic in the myCar class, not the Ref<> class, so that this logic only applies when getting/setting this **one** instance of Ref (after all, different instances of Ref<> variables will need different property logic, it's not always the same for every Ref<> type variable).

Comment: can you explain "property for the class `aggregating` it"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a generic property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271347/making-a-generic-property)

Answer (score 0):

I realized I different way to think about my question, and resultingly googled "C# Generic Property" and found what I think I'm looking for. (such as [Generic Property in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587236/generic-property-in-c-sharp))

Comment: then your question is Duplicate question