# Is there a way to perform a type specific action in a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

```cs
class Class1<T>
{
    T Value;

    void Method1()
    {
        if(Value is int)
            Value = 42;//CS0029
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make code like this work?

Comment: Why use generics if you need to do this?

Comment: @Magnus this is a reduced version of my code, just to show the problem.

Comment: What task you want to solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587236/generic-property-in-c-sharp may help you

Comment: the question is not clear, your intent as to what you are trying to achieve is unclear. is the main method just badly named or are you trying to modify startup class, and if so why... what will it achieve. Nothing in this example code is making sense, please add some detail as to why and what you are trying to do. can you make this work...as it is no, as what to work, without and understanding of what you are trying nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but usually there is something wrong with the code if you need to do this in a generic class.

```
if (Value is int)
   Value = (T)(object)42;
```