# Function signature is different when it's part of a type (it's not generic anymore)

Tags: f#

Why do the signatures of these functions differ?

This function:

```
type a () = 
    member this.ThirdElementOfTupleFromListToSequence = function 
        | (q, w, ids) -> (q,w, (List.toSeq ids))
```

has this signature: `(obj * obj * obj list -> obj * obj * seq<obj>)`

and when I assign the same function using `let`:

```
let ThirdElementOfTupleFromListToSequence = function 
    | (q, w, ids) -> (q,w, (List.toSeq ids))
```

it has this signature: `('a* 'b * 'c list -> 'a * 'b * seq<'c>)`

both function aren't used anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not defining a method, but a property whose value happens to be a function. And in .NET, properties cannot be generic.

In order to make it a method, you need to make it explicit in the declaration:

```
type a () =
    member this.ThirdElementOfTupleFromListToSequence(q, w, ids) =
        (q,w, (List.toSeq ids))
```

Or to make it more similar to your original version

```
type a () =
    member this.ThirdElementOfTupleFromListToSequence(arg) =
        match arg with
        | (q, w, ids) -> (q,w, (List.toSeq ids))
```

(Note that these two versions are actually different -- the first one is a method with three arguments, and the second one is a method with one argument which is a tuple).

Comment: Wow this is a case of leaking abstraction if I ever saw one. So the funcion patternmatching syntax returns different things when used in different situations?

Comment: You can fix this by making the type generic as well.

Comment: albertjan: not exactly. The idea is that a generic expression actually has infinitely many types. For example, `id` has type `'a -> 'a`, therefore it also has type `int -> int`, `obj -> obj`, `('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b)`, etc. When a generic expression is used in a given context, some constraints from the context may restrict the type. For example, in `id 2`, the type of `id` is constrained to `int -> int` because of the argument. The same phenomenon happens here: the type of the function is constrained because of the fact that it is affected to the value of a property.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the type signatures are different is because the CLR does not support generic properties; see: [Why does C# not allow generic properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620883/why-does-c-sharp-not-allow-generic-properties)

In your first example, the compiler infers the generic parameters just as it does for the `let`-bound example, but it has to "fill in" the generic parameters since it isn't allowed to create a generic property. The compiler uses `obj` in place of the generic parameters because that's guaranteed to work.

Comment: it all started with this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx) where I read that `match x with |` and `function |` are the same. Doesn't literally say that though. They could have stressed you're creating a lambda when you use function.

Comment: I agree, it would make sense for the documentation on the `function` keyword to note that it's equivalent to `fun x -> match x with`.

Comment: It does actually say it: "The pattern matching function shown in the previous syntax is equivalent to the following." but the paragraph is not very clear.