# How do you define a property to hold a generic interface type?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Consider the following interface...

```
public interface ILibraryService<T>
where T : Library
{
    ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> AvailableLibraries { get; }
}
```

I want to define a static property which can hold any object which implements this interface, like this pseudo-code...

```
public static class Services
{
    public static ILibraryService<T> LibraryService { get; set; }
}
```

...but I can't figure out how to define the property.  I know it's something simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: That looks exactly right. Does this not compile?

Comment: Nope! Try it for yourself!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C# not allow generic properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620883/why-does-c-sharp-not-allow-generic-properties). You are right!  Learn something new every day. I think that thread is pretty exhaustive,

Answer (score 0):

Are any of these what you're after? To my knowledge, Microsoft deliberately avoided giving us the ability to add type clauses on properties.

```
public static class Services
{
    public static ILibraryService<T> GetLibraryService<T>() 
        where T : Library
    {
        return null; // ...
    }
}

public static class Services<T>
    where T : Library
{
    public static ILibraryService<T> LibraryService { get; set; }
}

public static class Services<T>
    where T : ILibraryService<Library>
{
    public static T LibraryService { get; set; }
}

public static class Services<TService, TLibrary>
    where TService : ILibraryService<TLibrary>
    where TLibrary : Library
{
    public static ILibraryService<TLibrary> LibraryService { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Aaah... I got excited there before I realized your first example is a function, not a property.  No idea why they limit the latter when the former is fine.  But I guess the answer is I can't do it as a property, which is what I was hoping for.