# Implementing properties with help of enum operator

Tags: c#, .net, properties, enums

I'm a beginner in C#. I have a class named `config` with one string field named `kye`.

When I apply the `GET` property of the class, the property has to return one variable `kye` in different types (`Int` or `bool` or `String`).

I need to implement this with help of `enum` operator. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Seems to be an [X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: Related: [making a generic property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271347/making-a-generic-property/271356#2713560)

Comment: @Michael Please may I ask why do you want to keep a property in config that can be of 3 different types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing built into the language as far as I know so you'll have to do it manually. One straightforward way will be:

```
public object GetKye(KyeType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case KyeType.String:
            return this.kye;
        case KyeType.Int32:
            return Int32.Parse(this.kye);
        case KyeType.Bool:
            return this.kye.ToLower().Equals("true");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This removes the need to do a cast in code but is not safe. It needs plenty of error handling around it.

```
public T Kye<T>(KyeEnum Key)
{
    return (T)kye;
}
```

Or is this what you're after:

```
public Tuple<int, bool, string> Kye(KyeEnum Key)
{
    return new Tuple<int, bool, string>(nKye, bKye, sKye);
}
```