# Of which elements does Generics allow parameterization by type?

Tags: c#, generics

This is a question from some tests. Question is "Of which elements does Generics allow parameterization by type?"
and 5 variants of answers:

> 1. Classes
> 2. Structs
> 3. Methods
> 4. Events
> 5. Fields

On first glance question is very easy, but I'm not sure about correct answers. Let's step by step.

1. Classes.

We can write something like

```
class SuperKeyType<K, V, U>
    where U : System.IComparable<U>
    where V : new()
{ }
```

so, Classes can be parameterized by type. The same with Structs.

About methods. We can write the following:

```
class GenericList<T>
{
    // CS0693 
    void SampleMethod<T>() { }
}
```

so, methods too.

About Events and Fields:

```
class Foo<TValue> {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public TValue TypedValue {
        get {
            return (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(Value, tyepof(TValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Property is parametrized by type, correct (the same with Events)? But on the following page

[Making a generic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271347/making-a-generic-property)

I see the following answer:

> Properties, events, constructors etc can't be generic - only methods
>   and types can be generic. Most of the time that's not a problem, but I
>   agree that sometimes it's a pain. Brannon's answer gives two
>   reasonable workarounds.

I this place I ask itself - What means under "parameterization by type" at all? Property above is parametrized by type or not?
What is correct answer:

> 1. true
> 2. true
> 3. true
> 4. false
> 5. false

or

> 1. true
> 2. true
> 3. true
> 4. true
> 5. true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Property is parametrized by type, correct (the same with Events)?

No, it's not. There's no type parameter on the property itself - you've got it on the *class*.

Compare that with your method example:

```
class GenericList<T>
{
    // CS0693 
    void SampleMethod<T>() { }
}
```

... which would be clearer as

```
class NonGenericType
{
    void GenericMethod<T>() { }
}
```

Note how the type parameter (`T`) is introduced in the method signature, *not* on the class.

You can't specify a type parameter for fields, properties, events, constructors or finalizers.

A generic property would have to look something like:

```
// Not valid: properties can't be generic. But imagine...    
public T Value<T> { get; set; }
```

Likewise a generic constructor would be something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    // Not valid: constructors can't be generic. But imagine...
    public Foo<T>(T initializationValue)
    {
        // Note that this isn't constructing a Foo<T> -
        // Foo is a non-generic type. It's only the constructor
        // that is generic.
    }
}
```

A generic field is even weirder as a concept. What could it possibly mean?

```
private int field<T>;
...
int x = field<string>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Classes, Structs and Methods. The fact that you use a parametrized type as the type of the property does not mean the property itself is parametrized. The class of its type is.