# How to create generic property in model class using asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public class A
{
   public int Val {get; set;}
   public int B {get; set;}
   public T C{get; set;} // make generic property
}
```

How can I create generic property in model class using asp.net core. In above code I want to make

> "C" property as a generic property and convert that property into particular class.

In "C" will be dynamic property.

Example

```
public Class D
{
  public int Value1 {get; set;}
}

public Class E
{
  public int Value2 {get; set;}
}
```

The "C" property have either D or E

Comment: You need to declare the class as `public class A<T>`

Comment: public object C {get; set;}  ?

Comment: In an instance of A, attributes cannot have two types at the same time, either create two instances of A, or the two types have an inheritance relationship

Comment: Generics allow your implementation to be oblivious to the type of the property, but you must still define the exact type when you use it. eg `List<X>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a generic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271347/making-a-generic-property)

Comment: Properties can not be generic, only classes, interfaces, methods, deletgates can be  generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A<T>
{
   public int A {get; set;}
   public int B {get; set;}
   public T C {get; set;} 
}
```

And use it like this：

```
var a = new A<D>()
```

OR

```
var a = new A<E>()
```

[Generic classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)

Comment: I means to say that "C" property will be dynamic property where We can add any types of class.

Comment: Maybe you should explain how you want to use it

Comment: @Unknow,the answer of `FatTiger` is correct.You can try to use `var aD = new A<D> { C = new D() };var aE = new A<E> { C = new E() };`,so that C can be type D or E.